# Customize Spring Zuul Dynamic Path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have a Spring Boot application that leverages Zuul for reverse proxy routing several microservices. Formerly, we used Apache, which could account for the desired host.

My pseudo-configuration:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    app1:
      path: /path/conflict/**
      url: https://microservice1.mydomain.com/
    app2:
      ## only route for certain hosts!
      path: /path/conflict/**
      url: https://microservice2.mydomain.com/
```

Obviously, this is an invalid configuration since there is a `path` conflict with both `app1` and `app2`. I want the routing to be conditioned on the source host--formerly, we were able to do this with Apache.

I suspect there is a way to achieve this via Spring Zuul, since the pattern in Spring is to override-the-thing-you-want, but I'm not sure exactly what needs to be overridden/configured.

How can I achieve dynamic routing (specifically, for the inbound host)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using eureka for discovery?

If you are: you don't need to specify the route to any dynamic service.

For example, if you have a service with `server.port=0` on the `application.properties`, eureka will allocate a random port to each new instance. So, lets say that your service name is user-service, when you instantiate it, eureka allocate it to port 40000 (for example).

So, when a client consumes the gateway API, it will look for something like this: http://localhost:8080/user-service/... . The service is identified by the user-service on URL, it was made in runtime, you don't need to write this rule in any `.yml` or `.properties` file.

Comment: No, not currently using Eureka; but your suggestion illustrates a consideration that might help to support it (was considering it for other reasons). Thanks!